# Correct usage of variables in a batch script?

Tags: mysql, variables, batch-file

I need the script because a DB schema has changed and I have to fill a new table with some values (these have to be calculated using a php class). That was just a short summary, for a small overview).

Here's the first thing I can't figure out. I'm new to scripts so I was watching a few basic/beginner guids. In the shell (windows) I can run:

```
mysql -B -D www -h xxx -u yyy -pzzz -e "show tables"
```

this prints me all tables. Fine. If I try something similar in a batch script just to test if a can use variables

```
#!/bin/bash
V=10 // or V="10" // or V=$10, i saw all of it
mysql -B -D www -h xxx -u yyy -pzzz -e "select * from session_content_score where score_id<$V"
```

I'm always getting the error `The command V cannot be found`. I tried every declaration I could find. Whats the problem? How can I make usage of variables, because I need them for fulfilling my task?

Comment: You are confusing [tag:batch-file] (on Windows) with [tag:bash] (on Unix)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to set a variable in a windows batch script is:

```
SET foo=bar
echo %foo%
```

A good windows batch tutorial is here:
[Windows batch tutorial](http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/index.html)

You should question whether you are doing the right thing when you want to populate your database from windows batch scripts :)